# Put buttons behind each other programatically

Tags: swift, uibutton, swift2

I create a few buttons programmaticaly. This can be buttons between 2/4 buttons.

My question is how do I set them after each other programmatically and make sure they are aligned vertically no matter the amount(2/4)? This is what I do

```
for button in optionButtons {
        button.frame = CGRectMake(220, 280, 150, 150) // x value should change?
        button.addTarget(self, action: "pressedOption:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.view.addSubview(button)
        })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (index, button) in enumerate(optionButtons) {
    button.frame = CGRectMake(220 * (index + 1), 280, 150, 150) // x value should change?
    button.addTarget(self, action: "pressedOption:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    })
}
```

Thats only example you have to amend your x point logic (220 * (index + 1)) to layout it as you want. The key here is using index.